# How to use a parameter for a SQL Server query that is part of the query itself using SqlDataReader in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

**Background**

I am trying to retrieve the count of occurrences of a user in the database at the same time as returning the data set. How do I accomplish this? My code is below of what I have so far.

If I hard code the username, for the row, I get the expected output. However, I am having problems declaring a parameterized query variable with this code. Any help would be appreciated. I have been working on this for quite some time now.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnStr))
    {
        string Command = "SELECT TOP 3 *, Counter = (select Count(User) from Projects where [User]='jmoore00' AND Account = 'ACTIVE') FROM Projects";

        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(Command, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();  

            SqlDataReader rdr = comm.ExecuteReader();

            ListView.DataSource = rdr;
            ListView.DataBind();

            rdr.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Above, 'jmoore00' should be scalar variable @User but how do I appropriately declare and use the variable with value equaling rdr["user"] if I am using the code the way it is?

Comment: why a count(user) and a [user], why not count([user])

Comment: So you are not sure how to create parameterized query and pass parameter value to it?

Comment: Not in this case, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use Stored Procedure in you sql.as a specific user try to retrieve its data, do add number of this occurrence to a field in your sql.
each user has a unique field which can be in access with their users or userID.
but i think it will increase transaction time .

hope it would be helpful

Comment: I'd prefer to not use stored procedures for this and keep the sql inline. It really is just a simple databse query but the issue is with the scalar variable.

Comment: @jason, as i understood your problem just accomplished by stored procedure .mabye i am wrong i don't know by the way

Comment: thanks for your input. I will try this at some point probably as a last resort if I don't get another version working.

Comment: I used a stored procedure and a function to calculate the correct count on each row. Very clean, quick and easy compared to using inline SQL.

Comment: @jason,glad to hear that.